# Edge - weight association

Tags: c, minimum-spanning-tree, igraph

I'm working in C with igraph library.

I need to calculate the the minimum spanning tree of a graph, using the following call:

```
igraph_minimum_spanning_tree_prim( &input_graph, &mst_tree, &w);
```

where:

- ***input_graph:*** The graph to be processed. Is a ***igraph_t*** type.
- ***mst_tree:*** the mst tree returned by the function. Is a ***igraph_t*** type.
- ***w:*** Vector with the weigth of each edges of  input_graph graph.Is a ***igraph_vector_t*** type.

as is requested in the  igraph library, the association between  edges and  weigths is given by their index, that is, the first edge in the  ***input_graph*** has a weight given by the first element of ***w*** vector, the weight of the second edge is given by the second element of ***w*** vector, and so on.

Since the edges of ***mst_tree***  are a subset of the edges of  ***input_graph*** ( consequently, the amount of edges in *input_graph* and in *mst_tree* are differents), is not possible get the edges weight of ***mst_tree***, by associating their  index.

There is some igraph function to get the weight of each edges in ***mst_tree***, only knowing ***mst_tree***, ***input_graph*** and w?

Guillermo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In igraph 0.5.4, there is no such function, sorry :( In igraph 0.6 the minimum spanning tree API will change a bit so there will be another function with the following signature:

```
int igraph_minimum_spanning_tree(const igraph_t* graph, igraph_vector_t* res, const igraph_vector_t* weights);
```

where `res` will contain the indices of the edges that constitute the spanning tree. igraph 0.6 is not released yet but it's pretty stable, so you might want to try and upgrade to igraph 0.6 (if you don't mind a few API changes here and there).

*Disclaimer: I am one of the authors of igraph.*

Comment: Hi Tamás. Good. The new function cool. I'm evaluation to upgrade. I am using only a few function, but I need speed. 

I will compare the time complexity between the old and new implementation of the   igraph_minimum_spanning_tree. If is not available time complexity of the last vertion, could you tell me it?

By the way, I am working in solve the generalized spanning tree program, using parallel genetic algorith. Do you know some work about GSTM or some one working on it. I am looking for test intances to compare result.
Thank a lot,
Guillermo Parada.

Comment: The new version should have exactly the same time complexity as the old implementation. As for GSTM, no, I don't know anyone working on it.